# Migrate latest stable HUDSON to latest stable LTS JENKINS

Tags: jenkins, hudson, continuous-integration

I am having issues migrating a HUDSON server with several jobs to JENKINS
Jenkins claim you can upgrade easily from hudson but also mention it is only for version 1.395 or less (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Upgrading+from+Hudson+to+Jenkins)

Now i have tried different ways like replaying the hudson war file with jenkins war file but that doesnt work

I have also tried swapping the .hudson directory of user running hudson with .jenkins on the new JENKINS server and that doesn't work either

Only constant problem in all i have tried is that everything copied well including jobs and users and passwords BUT jobs themselves don't copy well like they never have the build steps like the bash script part which contains the jobs

Anyone know work around from migrating hudson 3.2.2 to Jenkins 1.596.2?

Thanks